# Get last modified time of file in linux

Tags: c, linux, timestamp, last-modified

I am working on a C program where I need to get the last modified time of the file. What the program does is a function loops through each file within a directory and when a particular file(s) is found it calls another function to check that the last modified times of the file.

Within the directory there is a `mylog.txt.1`, `mylog.txt.2` and `mylog.txt.3` etc. When I list the directory in linux using the ll command I can see that `mylog.txt.1` and `mylog.txt.2` were modified on the 4th May and `mylog.txt.3` was modified on the 3rd May.

When the program checks each of these files however, it is always returning 3rd may. Below is the code that I am using.

```
void getFileCreationTime(char *filePath)
{
    struct stat attrib;
    stat(filePath, &attrib);
    char date[10];
    strftime(date, 10, "%d-%m-%y", gmtime(&(attrib.st_ctime)));
    printf("The file %s was last modified at %s\n", filePath, date);
    date[0] = 0;
}
```

I've tried all the different variations of `st_ctime`, i.e. `st_mtime` and `st_atime` but they all return 3rd may.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: maybe cleanup first: why pass a size of 20 to `strftime` while the buffer is 10 long? why not check the return value of `stat`? If `stat` fails, you're parsing a garbage value.

Comment: make sure you are passing different filepath, also "attrib.st_ctime" will give the "time of last status change", if you are looking for "time of last modification" you need to use  "attrib.st_mtime"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is one of those cases where timezones matter. You're getting `gmtime` of the `st_mtime`. You should instead be using `localtime` viz.

```
strftime(date, 20, "%d-%m-%y", localtime(&(attrib.st_ctime)));
```

this is because `ls` uses your timezone information, and when you used `gmtime` as part of the display, it deliberately omitted any timezone information.

Comment: I would still recommend a lot more error checking in your function, though

Answer (score 26):

This worked fine for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void getFileCreationTime(char *path) {
    struct stat attr;
    stat(path, &attr);
    printf("Last modified time: %s", ctime(&attr.st_mtime));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Things to fix:

- Use the proper field, i.e. `st_ctime`.
- Check that `stat()` succeeds before using its result.
- Use `strftime(date, sizeof date, ...` to remove the risk of using the wrong buffer size.

I first suspected that your filesystem simply didn't support tracking the last-modified time, but since you say that other tools manage to show it, I suspect the code is breaking for whatever reason.

Could it be that the filenames are not full path names, i.e. they don't include the proper directory prefix?